# Postgresql equal to operation not working

Tags: postgresql

I encountered a problem that the equal to(`=`) operation in where clause not working as expected.

I have a table `mytable` with the schema defined as follows:

```
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id           | text                     |           | not null |
 identifier   | text                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "mytable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "mytable_identifier_idx" btree (identifier)
```

There is one record in the table with the values shown as follows:

```
mydatabase=> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 'd78ce235-6c70-4846-ae37-2dfbe2fabd52';
                  id                  |         identifier         
--------------------------------------+----------------------------
 d78ce235-6c70-4846-ae37-2dfbe2fabd52 | options_education_level_sg 
(1 row)
```

When I use the following query, it returns no results.

```
mydatabase=> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE identifier = 'options_education_level_sg';
 id | identifier 
----+------------
(0 rows)
```

But if I check whether the value of the `identifier` equals to the one I provided in the where clause, it says it is `true`.

```
mydatabase=> SELECT identifier = 'options_education_level_sg' FROM mytable WHERE id = 'd78ce235-6c70-4846-ae37-2dfbe2fabd52';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Another interesting thing is that if I use the following query, then it will return the correct result.

```
mydatabase=> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE identifier IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'options_education_level_sg';
           id                         |         identifier         
--------------------------------------+----------------------------
 d78ce235-6c70-4846-ae37-2dfbe2fabd52 | options_education_level_sg 
(1 rows)
```

My postgresql version is

```
version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.16 (Debian 10.16-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Does anyone know what might be the reason that causes this problem? Thanks

(Edited)
Add more information:

```
mydatabase=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE identifier = 'options_education_level_sg';
                                                          QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=4.34..27.83 rows=7 width=146) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (identifier = 'options_education_level_sg'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_identifier_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (identifier = 'options_education_level_sg'::text)
 Planning time: 0.095 ms
 Execution time: 0.049 ms
(6 rows)
```

```
mydatabase=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE identifier IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'options_education_level_sg';
                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..217.53 rows=7 width=146) (actual time=0.481..1.649 rows=5 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (identifier IS DISTINCT FROM 'options_education_level_sg'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 5610
 Planning time: 0.123 ms
 Execution time: 1.681 ms
(5 rows)
```

```
mydatabase=> show search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

Comment: Did you recently update your operating system? Maybe your locale libraries changed. See [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) for details. Try `reindex mytable`. Btw: UUIDs should be stored in a column defined as `uuid` not as `text` - that would be way more efficient.

Comment: That seems seriously broken. I don't see any indexes that might be involved. Please post the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your_query>` for both variants: with `=`, and with `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`. You did not mess with the system table `pg_operator`, did you? Your `search_path`?

Comment: There is an index on the `identifier` column, my first post missed it. I have added the information about the explanation of the queries and the `search_path`. I think we didn't touch the `pg_operator` table.

Comment: Your index must be broken. `REINDEX INDEX mytable_identifier_idx;`

Comment: Appreciated for the information @a_horse_with_no_name. We have 2 DBs running on 2 different os, one is Debian 9 and the other is Debian 10. The issue happens on the one that is running on Debian 10. In the end, we recreated the DB on Debian 9 and the problem solved.